# Php random odd or even

Tags: php, arrays, random

I want him to randomly pick 5 numbers from the string I entered and check them to see if they're even or odd
This is the code I made but I don't want 0 included:

```
    <?php
$s = array();
$tek =array();
$cift =array();
$tamsayi = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

for( $i=0; $i<5; $i++){

    $s [$i]= array_rand($tamsayi);
}
echo "Oluşturulan rastgele dizi : ";
  foreach ($s as $el) {
    echo $el;
  }
  for($j = 0; $j<5;$j++){
      if($s[$j] % 2 == 0){
        $cift[$j]=$s[$j];
      }else{
          $tek[$j]= $s[$j];
      }
  }
  echo '<br>';
  echo "Çift sayılar : ";
  echo '<br>';
  foreach ($cift as $eli) {
    echo $eli;
    echo '<br>';
  }
  echo "Tek sayılar : ";
  echo '<br>';
  foreach ($tek as $elin) {
    echo $elin;
    echo '<br>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Or is there a short way I can do this

Comment: Where's the string? Do you mean the array `$tamsayi`?

Comment: yes @RoAchterberg

Comment: `array_rand` does not pick a random _value_ from the array, it picks a random _key_. The keys of your array here go from 0 to 9. You should use the key to access the corresponding array value again: `$s[$i]= $tamsayi[array_rand($tamsayi)];`

Comment: Thank you very much, thanks to your help, @CBroe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$finalArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $key = array_rand($array);
    $random = $array[$key];
   if($random % 2 == 0){
       $finalArray["even"][] = $random;
   } else {
       $finalArray["odd"][] = $random;
   }
}   
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");

?>
```

Output will look smth like this:

```
Array
(
    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 8
        )

    [odd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

And if you want number to appear only once:

```
<?php

$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$finalArray = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $key = array_rand($array);
    $random = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
   if($random % 2 == 0){
       $finalArray["even"][] = $random;
   } else {
       $finalArray["odd"][] = $random;
   }

}   
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");

?>
```

Which will print allways unique values, like:
Array

```
(
    [odd] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 7
        )

    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for inspiration. This outputs an array of 5 values, indicating their parity.
Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parity"]=>
    string(3) "odd"
    ["value"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parity"]=>
    string(3) "odd"
    ["value"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parity"]=>
    string(3) "odd"
    ["value"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parity"]=>
    string(4) "even"
    ["value"]=>
    int(6)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["parity"]=>
    string(4) "even"
    ["value"]=>
    int(4)
  }
```

Code:

```
<?php

$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$numItems = count($a);

$selectedValues = [];
for ($i = 0, $l = 5; $i < $l; $i++)
{
    $selectedValue = $a[mt_rand(0, $numItems - 1)];
    $selectedValues[] =
        [
            'parity' => !($selectedValue % 2)?'even':'odd',
            'value' => $selectedValue
        ];
}

var_dump($selectedValues);
```